# How to login or sign in to a website inside my program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make my Winforms program have a button, which when pressed does the following:

1. Open a browser
2. Navigate to a website
3. Reads the username and password from a file or textbox
4. Login to the website or even take information from my program and sign in.

For example, I would like to do this with a site like Facebook or a forum.
Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like one 1password https://agilebits.com/onepassword?

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted , You can use WebBrowser Control? if that not then you need something to be stored at server end. Not sure if WinForms can access cookies directly .

Comment: I think you're asking too much in this question. Making a WinForms application is an assignment in itself if you're not experienced with it. Browser automation is another concept to practice. Also, it would be easier to give a more direct answer if you were more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; this is technically possible.

For making a WinForms application, I don't think this site is appropriate, since it's about specific, narrower questions.

For opening the web browser, navigating to pages, and logging in, look into browser automation libraries. I recommend [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) because it works with several browsers and seems to be the most mature one. You can add it to your project using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/).

Here's some example code for doing this with Facebook:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var facebookDetails = new WebPageAuthenticationDetails
        {
            HomePageAddress = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/"),
            UsernameLocator = By.Id("email"),
            PasswordLocator = By.Id("pass"),
            SubmitLocator = By.XPath("//input[@value='Log in']"),
        };

        //Don't dispose this or the browser will be closed after logging in.
        var browserDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Or use a different browser if you want (Firefox is easiest to use, though)
        var pageAccessor = new WebPageAccessor(browserDriver, facebookDetails);
        pageAccessor.LogIn("example_username", "example_password");
    }
}

class WebPageAccessor
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;
    private readonly WebPageAuthenticationDetails pageDetails;

    public WebPageAccessor(IWebDriver driver, WebPageAuthenticationDetails details)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.pageDetails = details;
    }

    public void LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(pageDetails.HomePageAddress);

        if (pageDetails.LogInLinkLocator != null)
            Click(pageDetails.LogInLinkLocator);

        Type(pageDetails.UsernameLocator, username);
        Type(pageDetails.PasswordLocator, password);
        Click(pageDetails.SubmitLocator);
    }

    private void Click(By locator)
    {
        driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
    }

    private void Type(By fieldLocator, string text)
    {
        driver.FindElement(fieldLocator).SendKeys(text);
    }
}

class WebPageAuthenticationDetails
{
    public Uri HomePageAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Only needed if a log-in link first needs to be clicked.
    /// </summary>
    public By LogInLinkLocator { get; set; }
    public By UsernameLocator { get; set; }
    public By PasswordLocator { get; set; }
    public By SubmitLocator { get; set; } //Because some sites don't use HTML submit buttons to submit
}
```

Choosing a browser automation library can be difficult. If you don't know which one to use, just do some Google searching; it's been discussed before.

Comment: Isn't selenium related to automated testing. correct me if wrong?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad, it's used for automated testing, but you can use it for whatever you want.

Comment: @Sam i think it takes time to work with the link you gave. can you explain a little that how it works and is webdriver the best way to work with this? is this just some dll library to add to my project and work with functions or.....?

Comment: @virtouso, if my answer isn't giving you enough information, you should probably unaccept it. I'll see if I can put together some more information for you.

Comment: @virtouso, I've updated the answer to give you more information and some working example code.

Comment: @Sam thank you. you made it so easy :d